# Change wordpress front language at the same time as admin according to user profile

Tags: wordpress

It is possible now to define a language in Wordpress for each user in his profile. The problem is that only the admin side (dashboard) is concerned and not the front. 
I would like to change both front and back language of each user when I choose the language is his profile (like it is implemented when we go to "settings" - "general" - "choose site language", the language is changed for both sides but for default configuration, not for a specific user).
If you have any idea,
Thanks.

Comment: That's OK, I found a great plugin called "JSM's User Locale Selector for the WordPress Toolbar" that does the job perfectly. Thanks @David.J.

Answer (score 0):

The [WPML plugin](https://wpml.org/) allows you to do this.

Within **Users => Your Profile**, the **WPML language settings** will allow each user to choose their own language preference.

Thanks.